# How to change the position and size of the tooltip in dimple.js

Tags: javascript, dimple.js

Is there any way to change the tooltip position on top of the bar chart and its size in dimple.js charts.

if there are any way please let me know. I have changed the text of the tooltip using "getTooltipText". Now I have to change the positon and size of the tooltip.

here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/pwr7043d/7/

```
var yMax = 1.2;
            var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("body", 370, 230);
             var data = [{
            "Brand":"A", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":10 },
            { 
            "Brand":"B", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":20 }];
            var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, data);
            myChart.setBounds(120, 10, 170, 150)

            var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
            var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SalesVolume");
            var s = myChart.addSeries("SalesVolume",dimple.plot.bar);
            s.getTooltipText = function (e) {
                return [
                    ""+e.aggField[0]+""
                ];
            };
            s.barGap=0.7;
            myChart.draw();

            var defs = svg1.append("defs");
            defs.append("marker")
            .attr("id", "triangle-start")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 10)
            .attr("refY", 5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 10)
            .attr("markerHeight", 10)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append("path")
            .attr("class", "marker")
            .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");

             svg1.append("line")
            .attr("x1", 140)
            .attr("x2", 295)
            .attr("y1", y._scale(0.5))
            .attr("y2", y._scale(0.5))
            .attr("marker-start", "url(#triangle-start)");
```

Comment: Now i want to get the tool tip at the top of the bar.. how to get that..

Answer (score 2):

You will have to override the standard tooltip behaviour, which means you will define the entire tooltip style and content.

You can do this as follows for your series s:

```
     s.addEventHandler("mouseover", function (e){
                // Draw the text information
                svg1.selectAll(".dimple-hover-text")
                  .data([e.xValue, d3.format(",.f")(e.yValue)])
                    .enter()
                    .append("text")
                    .attr("class", "dimple-hover-text")
    // Set the x and y positions of your tooltip 
                    .attr("x", 200) 
                    .attr("y", function (d, i) { return myChart._yPixels() + 20 + i * 25; })
   //desired font style                    
                    .style("font-family", "courier new") 
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
   //desired font-size
                    .style("font-size", "30px")   
  //desired font-color    
                    .style("fill", "#ffccb6")          
                    .style("pointer-events", "none")
                    .text(function (d) { return d; });//the text to be displayed, taken from .data()

              });

              // Clear the text on exit
              s.addEventHandler("mouseleave", function (e) {
                svg1.selectAll(".dimple-hover-text").remove();
              });
```

You can add as much styling as you need for your tooltip this way and with a bit of css you can almost make the appearance as the default tooltip.
Here is the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwr7043d/16/)

I have not bothered to make the data in the tooltip exactly as in your original fiddle, but paid attention on enabling you to change the font and position of the tooltip.